# RestyGWT and Spring. How to manage Entities and models on Client. Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, gwt, resty-gwt

I am trying to switch `backend` of my `GWT` app to `Spring` using `RestyGwt`.
I followed this examples:

1. [ekito](http://www.ekito.fr/people/a-spring-boot-quickstart-with-gwtrest-client/)
2. [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-rest-services-gwt)

Now I wonder what to do with `Entities`. Can they be used in client? I've put them in `Shared` package, but unfortunately I am getting an error:

```
gru 09, 2015 11:06:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/restgwt] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.client.GWTBridge
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.sagar.restgwt.shared.OrderConfirmation.toString(OrderConfirmation.java:18)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
```

Here are my classes:

client side

```
@Path("/service")
public interface InfoService extends RestService {
    public static class Util {
        private static InfoService instance;

        public static InfoService getService() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GWT.create(InfoService.class);
            }
            Resource resource = new Resource(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "service");
            ((RestServiceProxy) instance).setResource(resource);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/loadInfo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void getInfo(MethodCallback<OrderConfirmation> callback);
}
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            InfoService.Util.getService().getInfo(
                    new MethodCallback<OrderConfirmation>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Method method, OrderConfirmation response) {
                            RootPanel.get().add(
                                    new Label(
                                            "message: " + response.message + "  - ready time: " + response.ready_time)
                                    );
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Method method,
                                Throwable exception) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            GWT.log("Error");

                        }

                    });
        }
    });
```

Server side

```
@Controller
public class RestGWTController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody OrderConfirmation handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //GreetingServiceEndpoint endpoint = greetingService.getGreetingServiceEndpointPort();

        OrderConfirmation confirmation = new OrderConfirmation();
        //confirmation.message = endpoint.sayHello();
        confirmation.message = "Hello";
        confirmation.ready_time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30;
        System.out.println("hit server");
        return confirmation;
    }
}
```

Shared module

```
public class OrderConfirmation {
    public String message;
    public Long ready_time;
    /**
     * Example of how to create an instance of a JsonEncoderDecoder for a data
     * transfer object.
     */
    public interface OrderConfirmationJED extends JsonEncoderDecoder<OrderConfirmation> {
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (GWT.isClient()) {
            OrderConfirmationJED jed = GWT.create(OrderConfirmationJED.class);
            return jed.encode(this).toString();
        }
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Now I think about `DTO` on `shared` module, and `Entity` on server. I this correct. 
My question is:

1. What is good design patern for this purpose.
2. Can server side Entity be serialised to json, and used on client side as Java object in gwt?

Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the gwt-servlet.jar dependency.

**Maven Configuration**

It needs to be `<scope>compile</scope>` which is the default. The other gwt-jars can be `<scope>provided</scope>`

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```